# Append URL of get_category_link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-post-type

I have a link that i wish to add the custom post type before the post name.

I want the url to read `website.com/catagory/custom_post_type/post_name`

Currently i have this, the problem is the last part, Its not showing the post type just the id.

`<li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $post_type ) ,$category->term_id ?> ">`

Is there a way i can fix this ?